# Can't pass req.params when using http-proxy-middleware ... NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, proxy, axios

I am new to Node, and I can't pass request parameters when using http-proxy-middleware..

It throws me 404 error

This is the express listener:

```
  app.put("/api/markets/:id",()=>{..code..});
```

This is the axios PUT request:

```
axios
  .put("/api/markets/" + idToPass, {..Object..})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

And this is the proxyMiddleware:

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy("/api/*", { target: "http://localhost:3050" }));
};
```

My client runs on localhost:3000 (react app)
And my server is on localhost:3050

When I open my browser network tab to inspect requests I see that call is being made to

```
localhost:3000/api/markets/idContent
```

not

```
localhost:3050/api/markets/idContent
```

as it is supposed to.

It works when I send it manually to

```
localhost:3050/api/markets/idContent
```

How can I fix this, any ideas?

Thx in advance

Comment: "When I open my browser network tab to inspect requests I see that call is being made to  localhost:3000/api/markets/idContent" which is expected. You are sending origin relative request that is proxied by your server (not redirected). You wont see the target url in the network tab.

Comment: Url doesent change when I make a request, sry I am pretty new to Node, are you saying it is expected that call is being made to localhost:3000/....

Comment: P.S. other axios request (get, post) that do not include /:id works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is with the proxy configuration. As of now it matches urls only one level deep.

Try `/api` or `/api/**` instead

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy("/api", { target: "http://localhost:3050" }));
};
```

Comment: It worked, I changed it to /api
console.log(Большое Спасибо)

Comment: @JozeV Glad I could help :)

Answer (score -1):

You are not specifying the base URL. Create an axios instance and specify the correct base URL:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3050'
});
```

And then make every axios requests using that instance:

```
instance
  .put("/api/markets/" + idToPass, {..Object..})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: This would cause CORS issues I believe OP is trying to avoid using proxy.

Comment: Thx, hope this will help someone, I tried the solution given by Yuri and it worked